# Linking in Visual Studio 2015 using subdirectories for source files C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linker, linker-errors

I am currently trying to solve a linker error in Visual studio 2015 and working on it for a while now and I don't know how to succeed.

I have a ProjectFolder in VS 2015 with two projects:

**project 1:**

Additional include directories set as: `.\trunk\`

My .h and .cpp files are located in a directory `.\trunk\` with several subdirectories `.\trunk\FooModule\`, `.\trunk\FooDefinitions\`

`.\trunk\FooModule\` containing:

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Foo();
    double getX();
    double getPI();
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <FooDefinitions\FooDefinitions.h>

Foo::Foo() : x(0.) {
}
double Foo::getX() {
    return x;
}
double Foo::getPI() {
    return PI;
}
```

`.\trunk\FooDefinitions\` containing:

**FooDefinitions.h**

```
#define PI 3.141;
```

`project1` exports the code to a library `Foo.lib` to the folder `.\lib\`.

---

`Foo.cpp` can include `Foo.h` because these files are in the same folder. `Foo.cpp` can also include `FooDefinitions.h` because `<...>` looks in the additional include directories, finds there the given subfolder `FooDefinitions` and in there the requested `.h` file. Everything compiles, I get a `.lib` file and everything is perfect.

---

Now **project2** wants to use the source code of project1 and the `.lib` file. Explicitely `project2` should perform later unitTests therefore `.lib` is neccessary.

Therefore in the settings of `project2` settings were set as follows (rightclick on projectname -> properties -> configuration properties):

-> Linker -> general -> additional library pathes: `.\lib\`

-> Linker -> input -> additional dependencies: `Foo.lib`

-> VC++-directories -> include directories: `.\trunk\`

project2 contains just one `.cpp` file with a main in it

**test.cpp**

```
#include <FooModule\Foo.h>
#include <iostream>

int main {
    Foo f();
    double y = f.getX();
    std::cout << y;

    return 0;
}
```

---

If I now want to compile `project2` I get the error:

> LNK2019 Foo.lib line 1, Reference on not resolved extern symbol "bool __cdecl ..."

and several other Linker errors like `LNK2011` and `LNK1120`.

I dont understand this because: I gave the compiler the `.lib` file and the header files of the used class and the compiler is not able to create an `Foo` object `f`. Furthermore he can't find the method `.getX()` on the object `f`.
Visual Studio finds the include `Foo.h` and displays `Foo` coloured like a defined class. Therefore I assume that the include succeded.

I can solve this Linker errors by changing the additional include directory of `project2` to `.\trunk\FooModule\;.\trunk\FooDefinitions\`. Now the Linker is able to find the symbols. But then `Foo.h` is not able to finde `FooDefinitions.h` anymore because the include path is not correct anymore.
The subdirectories `FooModule` and `FooDefinitions` exist for a reason and `#include <FooDefinitions\FooDefinitions.h>` should be like this for overview reasons.

So I guess it has something to do with the subfolders `FooModule` and `FooDefinitions`. But I like my subfodlers and I want to keep them.

What for Linker settings did I messed up? What am I doing wrong? What might be a solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are two things that look very suspicious: (1) Somehow you assume that `.\trunk\\`` directory listed as additional include directory in Project1 and `.\trunk\\`` directory listed as additional include directory in Project2 are the same directory. I can only imagine this happening if you have some fancy symbolic links or if both of your projects are residing in the same directory. (2) Include directories are used during compilation and can not effect linker behavior in any way.

Comment: (1) yes it is the exact same directory of course.
.\trunk is located somewhere on a server. It should not affect the code in any way where it is. 
Project2 should use the code of project1 (because it should perform unittests on it later. So therefore it has to include .\trunk. Don't know where the problem is.